# How does wavelength affects uncertainty in momentum & position?

Tags: momentum, atomic-physics, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, wavelength

The objective is to locate a microscopic particle, in the presence of light of known wavelength and adjustable accordingly.

> Brief on the setup.
> Let there be a box containing the particles to be located. The box has photons of wavelength lamda. We use a detector to try and find the momentum & position of particle. According to Heisenberg's Uncertainty Principle, we end up with some uncertainty in both position and momentum of the particle.

So now **what is the role of photon-particle interaction in the uncertainty of momentum and position ?** Does it decrease or increase the uncertainty in momentum when wavelength is decreased ?

Do the uncertainty in measurement of momentum increase as we decrease the wavelength or vice-versa? Also, I have read that uncertainty in position of the particle can be approximately equal to wavelength of light present: $∆x ≈ \lambda$. But I don't understand why it has to be like that?

Here, I am solely referring to the below expression:

$$∆x.∆p ≥ \frac{h}{4π}$$

I have read some answers relating to diffraction of light and resolution but I do not think those answer my question with terms to Heisenberg's Uncertainty Principle.

Comment: The momenta of particles that are described quantum mechanically are not measured using light, so you should make it clear what momentum you mean.

Comment: It is like asking, if the kind of light we incident on the particle affects the measurements in any way or not ? If yes then in what way

Comment: The way is described by the scattering crossections and calculated with feynman diagrams, and the momenta will follow the probability as calculated by those diagrams. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compton_scattering#Description_of_the_phenomenon

Comment: The smaller the wavelength of light the smaller the energy of the individual photons hitting the particle.The fina momenta after scattering obey the calculations. The delta(p)delta(x) does not apply, because the interaction is not a measurement of p. The measurement of p happens with a detector , not with the light.

Comment: I am not saying that light is used to measure. I want to know if wavelength light reduces or increases the uncertainty with which the detector is going to measure ∆p, ∆x

Comment: andI am replying that it is apples and oranges.

Comment: I humbly apologise, if I have misunderstood your comments the whole time due to lack of knowledge, but I am certain that my question is unanswered yet

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127050/discussion-between-goarkz-and-anna-v).